# Convert single line comments to multiline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comments, minify

I want to minify my JavaScript files, but single line comments have a problem and the minified line becomes commented.

Thus, I tried to transform / convert all single line comments to multiline comments.

I cannot do this manually as there are many js files and lot code.

Are there any online tools or methods accomplish this? 
Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: What all have you tried. Did yu have a look at the minification Libraries?

Comment: I was minifying using online tools only. No idea on libraries. How they work and all.

Comment: Did you try https://javascript-minifier.com/.
It removes the comments when minifying.

Comment: Sorry for silly question . But what if i want to retain comments in my minified file, as going further i want to unminify that code and develop further in that. Then my comments are lost.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in Production environment? I feel DEV environment may have comments but Prod should never have them.

Comment: Yes right. I can go for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome! Also try to have a pre-compilation for your FE source. That helps a Lot. #JustATip

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17469783/427146) on preserving certain comments

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are many ways to minify the package/build so it may depends on your minification process or commenting style which is causing this problem.

However I would like to share the my approach which I used without any issue/error.

I used grunt node minify i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-node-minify

Below is the commenting style I used. There are many ways to add a comments in JavaScript; Here is my recommendation / best practices:

using `//` is better than `/* */` because then you can use the latter to take out an entire block containing other comments. However, if you want to use an automatic documentation generation tool, you must use comments similar to javaDoc style.

This is an example that would work with YUI DOC (best one) http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/#start

```
/**
* This is a description
* @namespace My.Namespace
* @method myMethodName
* @param {String} str - some string
* @param {Object} obj - some object
* @param {requestCallback} callback - The callback that handles the response.
* @return {bool} some bool
*/
    function SampleFunction (str, obj, callback) {
         var isTrue = callback(str, obj); // do some process and returns true/false.
         return isTrue ;
    }
```

Other params examples: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

**Source:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126310/does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions/39391392#39391392

**Note-** I tried this with uglify also with single/multiline comments without any error.

i.e. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
/*/ Some comment /*/
</script>
```

Also very useful in multi-cursor when quickly commenting out some code chunk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).